# Container stop because of: "httpd: Could not open configuration file /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: No such file or directory", why?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am working on a Docker version of PyroCMS. This is the [repository](https://github.com/reypm/docker-pyrocms) I have with the latest files. As you can see I have a stack running: CentOS 7 (with Supervisord), MySQL, Apache and PHP. This is the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '2.1'
services:
    httpd:
        build: docker/httpd
        ports:
            - "8080:80"
        volumes_from:
            - php-fpm
    php-fpm:
        build:
            context: docker/php-fpm
            args:
                INSTALL_XDEBUG: "false"
                INSTALL_MONGO: "false"
                INSTALL_REDIS: "false"
                INSTALL_HTTP_REQUEST: "false"
                INSTALL_UPLOAD_PROGRESS: "false"
                INSTALL_XATTR: "false"
        depends_on:
            db:
                condition: service_healthy
    db:
        image: mysql
        healthcheck:
            test: "exit 0"
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
            MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
            MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
```

This is the `Dockerfile` for the `httpd` image:

```
FROM reynierpm/centos7-supervisor
RUN yum install -y httpd nano && \
    yum clean all && rm -rf /tmp/yum*
RUN rm -f /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf /etc/httpd/conf.d/* /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/*
COPY container-files /
EXPOSE 80
```

I am having a problem since the `httpd` container exit with status 1 and seeing the logs I got the following:

```
httpd_1  | httpd: Could not open configuration file /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: No such file or directory
```

At first glance you will say:

*you're deleting the files!!! in this line `RUN rm -f /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf /etc/httpd/conf.d/* /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/*`*

And you're right but if you take a closer look you'll see I am copying it back (because I am running a minimal Apache configuration) in the line:

```
COPY container-files /
```

I am not sure why the file can't be found and why the container is stopping and exiting, can any take a look to this and let me know where I am making a mistake if there is one?

Comment: I'd spin up a bash shell with a new container instance of the "httpd" service  container and manually investigate the directories. You may find that the `COPY` command is not placing the config files where you expect them to be. To do that: `docker-compose run --rm httpd bash`. I'm assuming the centos image has bash installed.

Comment: check what shows `docker run -it  httpd bash` and ls to check if your file is present

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this in your php-fpm Dockerfile:

```
VOLUME ["/data/www", "/etc/httpd"]
```

And this in docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
httpd:
    build: docker/httpd
    ports:
        - "8080:80"
    volumes_from:
        - php-fpm
```

So your httpd image ends up with a volume mount at `/etc/httpd`. The contents of that volume override whatever was baked into the `httpd` image at build time.

Comment: Yeah I figure it out just minutes ago but anyway there you go your points!